# How to retrieve data entered in input type ="number"?

Tags: php, html, string, post, input

If this is my HTML fourm

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>qrFileONEZES</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="delFourm.php" method="post">


Enter the position 1 - 20 of which to delete at:

 <input type="number" size="6" name="Delete at pos? :" min="1" max="20" value="1"><br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="enterz">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And that redirects me to another file, delFourm.php in which:

```
<?php

.
.
.


if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
    $numToDel = $_POST['Delete at pos? :']; // this is the num to del from qrFile?
    // echo "this is my test to see if value is sent? " . $numToDel;
}
else
{
echo "num wasnt obtained?";
}

echo "the number is " . $numToDel;
.
.
.
?>
```

Why is my output for `$numToDel` blank for output?

I get nothing for output when using echo, and I want to reference the number selected from the previous forum in later segments of code in this file. I have poor coding skills, so a detailed explanation would help.

Comment: Because, your POST array isn't valid. Do a `var_dump();` on it and see what comes up. If it comes up empty again; there's the problem. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything also.

Comment: Delete at pos , there are spaces, remove them or add underscores delete_at_pos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Change the name of your input to: `name="delete_at_post"`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>qrFileONEZES</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="delFourm.php" method="post">


Enter the position 1 - 20 of which to delete at:

 <input type="number" size="6" name="delete_at_post" min="1" max="20" value="1"><br>
<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit2" value="enterz">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

in your delFourm.php:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit2']))
{
    $numToDel = $_POST['delete_at_post']; // this is the num to del from qrFile?
    // echo "this is my test to see if value is sent? " . $numToDel;
}
else
{
echo "num wasnt obtained?";
}

echo "the number is " . $numToDel;

?>
```

You can read How set the name attribute in:

> http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-cdata

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work by using in the HTML fourm

```
other type test for input: <input type="number" name="numm" min="1" max="20"><br>
```

instead of:

```
 <input type="number" size="6" name="delete_at_post" min="1" max="20" value="1"><br>
```

Not sure why it didnt work though, not that it matters.

Comment: If you read my answer you will see that is the same. I edit with the correction of a little problem in delFourm.php. I forget the last t in $numToDel = $_POST['delete_at_post'];